# Why do I have two source controls in VsCode git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm noticing something weird whilst working on a project:

I removed the git folder for a clean start like this: `rm -rf .git`

Then I added the remote: `git remote add origin <url>`

And now VSCode shows me this:

[image: Source control image]

Why do I have the top source control *(p2000-raspberry)* even though I made a new git project, how do I remove this? Please help me out here, I only want the *p2000-receiver*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found out how to remove it, just right click on the title of the repository and press "close"

Answer (score 3):

i get the same bug with 2 icons, first is always empty even with change pending to be commited.
I can do right click to remove it but i don't get why i get two icons

[image]

Comment: Seems one of them (the one with ^ + G shortcut key) is related to GitLens.

Comment: This is an unrelated issue to the one described in the O.P.

Comment: @Alainlb I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: To resolve this issue, click and drag the icon that doesn't have the ability to code commit into the open panel of the one that does!